# Stripping Uppercase Words in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, split, parsing, vba

Stripping Uppercase Words in Excel VBA

I have an Excel sheet like this one:

```
A        B
1        Used CONTENT VERSION SYSTEM for the FALCON Project
2        USA beats UK at Soccer Cup 2008
3        DARPA NET’s biggest contribution was the internet
4        One big problem is STRUCTURED QUERY LANGUAGE queries on non-normalized data
```

I want to extract all of the words in UPPERCASE and generate a list with them:

```
A                             B
CONTENT VERSION SYSTEM        1
FALCON                        1
USA                           2
UK                            2
DARPA NET                     3
STRUCTURED QUERY LANGUAGE     4
```

I was thinking that I could check if “eachWord” == UCase(eachWord), but I don’t know how to handle phrases.  I also don’t know how to handle phrases that end in “apostrophe s”, “end parenthesis”, or punctuation.

I’ve been splitting words like this:
`IndividualWordsArray = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(workingRow, 2).Value)`

But that only makes an array based on space chars.  I thought it might help if, in addition to spaces, it could also split by these chars: “ ( ) : ‘ , . ? ! ;  After some searching, I find I can split a line by a char other than spaces, but only one delimiter at a time.

Anyone have any idea how to create a list with all of the uppercase words and phrases?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to take a copy of your text, replace all the delimiter characters with a space character, and then split using a space as your delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly slow way, but it does work (except it won't return NET from NET's). I just loop through the array of words and test each letter for caps. The `Option Compare Binary` statement is crucial.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Binary

Sub x()
    Dim IndividualWordsArray() As String, keeperArray() As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim allCaps As Boolean

    IndividualWordsArray = Split(ActiveCell)
    k = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(IndividualWordsArray)
        allCaps = True
        For j = 1 To Len(IndividualWordsArray(i))
            If Not Mid(IndividualWordsArray(i), j, 1) Like "[A-Z]" Then
                allCaps = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If allCaps Then
            ReDim Preserve keeperArray(k)
            keeperArray(k) = IndividualWordsArray(i)
            Debug.Print keeperArray(k)
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```